# Automating the adding in of values from a CSV to a List<class>

Tags: c#, list, csv

```
        A       B           C       D   E
Blood   0.02401 0.1104      0       0   1
Lung    0.0016  0.1104      13      0   0.36
Gut     0.0166  0.015456    19.3    0   0.035
Pancreas0.0010  0.001104    20.3    0   0.035
Spleen  0.0006  0.006072    6.8     0   0.22
Heart   0.0011  0.0054096   9.1     0   0.26
Muscle  0.1359  0.03069     7       0   0.04
Adipose 0.03297 0.007728    38.2    0   0.24
Kidney  0.0024  0.017112    10.5    0   0.16
Skin    0.0666  0.0064032   26.9    0   0.02
Brain   0.0019  0.00276     18.1    0   0.03
Bones   0.0255  0.013248    8.3     0   0.04
Liver   0.0128  0.004416    11.3    0.045   0.21
```

I have a method named FileReader which reads the file Parameter.csv (values above) and creates a List named Variables which contains only the number values.   I can get FileReader to read the organ name string and put it in the list before each respective set of values also.

```
    class Organ
    {
    public string name {get; set;}
    public double A {get; set;}
    public double B {get; set;}
    public double C {get; set;}
    public double D {get; set;}
    public double E {get; set;}
    }

void Main()
{
FileReader Parameters = new FileReader(@"C:\Parameter.csv");
var ListofOrgans = List<Organ>();
Organ Blood = new Organ();
Blood.name = "Blood";
Blood.A = Parameters.Variables[0];
Blood.B = Parameters.Variables[1];
Blood.C = Parameters.Variables[2];
Blood.D = Parameters.Variables[3];
Blood.E = Parameters.Variables[4];
ListofOrgans.Add(Blood);
}
```

Is there a way I can automate this so that I don't have to hard code all 77 values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this by using a StreamReader, something like this (I'm typing this from memory and it's late!):

```
var ListOfOrgans = new List<Organ>(); 
String tmp = null;
String [] tokens = null;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Parameter.csv"))
{
   while( !sr.EndOfStream )
   {
      tmp = sr.ReadLine();
      tokens = tmp.Split(' ');
      Organ foo = new Organ();
      foo.name = tokens[0];
      foo.A = Convert.ToDouble(tokens[1]);
      .
      .
      etc.

      ListOfOrgans.Add(foo);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [CsvHelper Library](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) allows you to [map by index or name](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Fluent-Class-Mapping) into a custom class, and directly create the collection of class instances.  However, it will still require you to specify which columns in the file map to which properties.

If your class property names match the CSV column names, it will work without any specifications.

Comment: if I have 
var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(filename));
var organList = csv.GetRecords<Organ>();
how do I access any of the parameters I just read?  or do I have to do more with this?

Comment: @BBH1023 If you do that, `organList` will be a `List<Organ>` already filled in - the properties will all be setup automatically.